# App Search API Validation Tool fails to find Link to Application (Universal Links)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to set up Universal Links for my app. It doesn't matter what domain I use or where I store my apple-app-site-association file (root or .well-known directory), the validation tool shows the same error: "Error cannot fetch app site association.". I use default apple-app-site-association file:

```html
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "HKJGHKJG.appName",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you fetch the file successfully with a browser or curl or wget?  Have you set the correct MIME type?  Is the file served using https?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, I can fetch file as well as I have correct MIME type set in .htaccess file:

<Files "apple-app-site-association">
    ForceType 'application/json'
</Files>

And I have https domain.

By the way, my error has changed to this: "sitename is returning 516. Please check your url and try again.". I did nothing specific other than added favicon and a couple of png files to root directory.

Comment: I'd like to mention that my app have not been released on appStore yet. Maybe this is the reason I keep getting the errors?

Comment: No, this all works before your app is released.  There is a setting you can add to your info.plist when in development mode so that the device bypasses Apple's CDN to avoid caching problems when you are updating your file, but that won't affect a validation